# Why do my profile picture alone blurred exactly in Leagues page while looking through Firefox 40.0.3?

Tags: discussion, images, profile-picture, firefox, browsers

In the [Stack Exchange Leagues Page of Webmasters](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/9/alltime/webmasters/2010-07-08/28169#28169), I have seen that my profile picture is blurred but **I can see others picture are clear only**. I checked my profile picture in my profile page and it's very clear. I have checked all the pages wherever my profile picture has been showing over the site and all looks good, then why do my profile picture alone blurred and exactly in Leagues page?

Leagues Page:

[image]

Profile Page:

[image]

[image]

If image size might be the reason means, in the above picture my profile picture size is very small but it is not blurred.

**Important Note:**

I checked the page through various browsers. Unfortunately the image is clear in Chrome as well as in IE but the problem exist in Firefox 40.0.3.

Comment: Wouldn't that make this a firefox issue, not a SE issue?

Comment: @Won't I didn't tag `Bug` in this question as I'm not sure what would be the problem, I asked this question.